# linking HTMLHelp.lib with x64

Tags: visual-c++, 64-bit, chm

i have a VS05 C++ (MFC) project which uses HtmlHelp (function HTMLHelpA, linked from HmleHelp.lib, which came from HTML HElp Workshop v1.4). the 32-bit version compiles and links fine.

the 64-bit version compiles fine, but gets an "unresolved external" error on HTMLHelpA, when linking.

so, my question is simple: is there a way to use HTMLHelp in x64?

Answer (score 2):

If you download the latest Windows SDK (6.0A), it contains both x86 and x64 versions of this library.